# "Trying to get property of non-object in" - custom mysqli class

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a custom class for MySQLi, but I keep receiving the error "Trying to get property of non-object in" when using `num_rows`. Can anyone help?

```
class db { 
    private $host = "***";
    private $user = "***";
    private $pass = "***";
    private $database;

    private $connection;
    private $result;
    public $sql;

    function __construct($database) {
        if (!empty($database)) $this->database = $database;
        $this->connection = new mysqli($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass,$this->database);
        return $this->connection;
    }

    public function fetchRowNum($sql) {
        if (!empty($sql)) {
            $this->sql = $sql;
            return $this->connection->query($sql)->num_rows;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Error fetching row");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `mysqli::query()` returns a `mysql_result` resource. Your query `$sql` fails for some reason and you perform no error check before attempting to get `mysql_result::$num_rows` from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) doesn't always return a [mysqli_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object, it can return `TRUE` and `FALSE` as well which would result in the error you are getting.

Store the return value of `query()` and check to see if it is `TRUE` or `FALSE` before you try to access it as an object and fetch the `num_rows` property.

From the manual about `mysqli::query()`:

> Returns **FALSE** on failure. For successful **SELECT**, **SHOW**, **DESCRIBE** or
>   **EXPLAIN** queries `mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result` object. For
>   other successful queries `mysqli_query()` will return **TRUE**.